# Decimalformat: unwanted replace of dot with comma in JTable

Tags: java, jtable, decimalformat

I have a problem displaying the numbers in JTable. If I try to format the number 3.456007 with DecimalFormat using:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
```

The output in JTable is **3,456** instead of **3.456**.
If I don't format the number than the result is correct with dot: **3.456007**
How can I show only 3 decimal places without losing the **dot** ?

Comment: What locale are you using?

Comment: Since I live in Austria I thought maybe because of the DE..but changing to US,GB was same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing to note here is that the "." character in your format does not mean dot. It means: **decimal separator corresponding to the Locale**.

You can have an actual "." by explicitly setting a Locale where the decimal separator is indeed a dot. Example:

```
    NumberFormat df = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println(df.format(12.3456)); //prints 12.346
```